# Output Dropdowlist to TPL file

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have some PHP code that works fine as is. However I want to output the Dropdownlist to my TPL file. How can I do this?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY SORT_ORDER ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === false) { echo "An error occurred."; }

?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="usrname" id="usrname">
<option>Select employ</option>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<option value="<? echo $rows['ID']; ?>"><? echo $rows['TITLE']; ?></option>
<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="<? echo $rows['ID']; ?>"><? echo $rows['TITLE']; ?></option>
```

u forget `php text in <?php .... ?>` ..please change this code like this..

```
<option value="<?php echo $rows['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['TITLE']; ?></option>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I think I need to assign it somehow:
    $tpl -> assign

I wanna pull it up from .tpl not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by .tpl ?

you can just transfer you "while (...) {...}" part to another file (say select.inc.php) and
include it

but if you want a $tpl object, create a class first, e.g in *template.class.php*:

```
class Template {

    private $file;
    public $result;

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function display() {
        ob_start();
        include $this->file;
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

include it and create template file *select.tpl*:

```
<select name="usrname" id="usrname">
<?
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($this->result)) {
?>
    <option value="<?=$rows['id']?>"><?=$rows['name']?></option>
<?
}
?>
</select>
```

finally create an instance and call display() method in your script:

```
$tpl = new Template('select.tpl');

$tpl->result = $result;

$tpl->display();
```